# Convert the difference between datetime.datetime field to seconds

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a piece of code where I have calulated the time taken for the algorithm to run through datetime as below.

```
begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()
#some algo code
datetime.datetime.now()-begin_time
```

I expected the output in seconds but it is in some different form as below:

```
0.000359
```

I am pretty sure that these are not seconds. How do i convert it to seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import time

tic = time.perf_counter()

#Your code here

toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f`'Your program took {toc - tic:0.2f} seconds to run')
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is calculated in hours so you just need to multiply it by 3600 to convert it to seconds.